# Symfony fatal error when trying to run configurator

Tags: php, symfony

I successfully completed the configuration check on `web/config.php` when installing Symfony on a U10 LAMP server, but now running across this error when trying to run `web/app_dev.php/_configurator/`:

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface' not found in /var/www/symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Registry.php on line 26
```

Did I forget to install something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing Doctrine bridge for some reason. I guess something went wrong when you installed vendors (github might have been down for a minute and it just skipped this part).

Try to reinstall vendors:

```
./bin/vendors install
```

Or just [download Symfony2](http://symfony.com/download) with pre-installed vendors.